# Control LED of iPhone in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anything strange about this code?

```
@IBAction func turnOnLed()
{
    var device = AVCaptureDevice(uniqueID: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    device.lockForConfiguration(nil)

    println(device.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On))

    if(device.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On)){
        device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On
    }
    device.unlockForConfiguration()

}
```

Simulating this on my real device is giving me that torchmode is not supporeted (iPhone 5S)

Answer (score 3):

AVMediaTypeVideo isn't a device unique id; you'll probably find that device is nil. If you want to grab a video device, try something like:

```
var device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
```